# Finding min/max. Optimization

Tags: optimization, x86

```
.loop:

    movups xmm1, [esi+ecx*4]
    movaps xmm2, xmm0
    movaps xmm5, xmm1

    pcmpgtd xmm2, xmm1

    andps  xmm0, xmm2
    andnps xmm2, xmm1
    orps   xmm0, xmm2

    pcmpgtd xmm5, xmm3

    andps  xmm3, xmm5
    andnps xmm5, xmm1
    orps   xmm3, xmm5

.cond:
    add ecx, 4
    js .loop
```

This is a base loop to find max/min among ints.
The my processor is AMD K8. I am not able to count cylces but I can compare that my code is slower than my friends who didn't use SIMD.
I cannot understand why. Is it this loop not optimal? Do you see a cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K8 only has 64bit execution units, so every 128b instruction is decoded into 2 m-ops.  Also, `movups` is more m-ops than `movaps` even when the address is aligned.  (Although according to Agner Fog's tables, it still has the same one per 2 cycle throughput as `movaps`.)

If you used branches in the scalar version, and the `min` and `max` don't change often, then branch prediction can make it run quite fast.

This is one of those cases where SIMD has to do so much more work that it's actually slower than scalar.  Although this SSE2 version might actually be better than scalar on CPUs with full-width vector units, like K10 or Merom. (or newer)

Of course, you'd get *far* better results with SSE4.1 `pmaxsd`/`pminsd`.