# Min/max. Scalar approach

Tags: x86

This subject is connected to:
[Finding min/max. Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644729/finding-min-max-optimization/37644968#37644968)

I rewrite function min_max from my the first post to scalar version. But is still too slow. Could you suggest me something?

```
    jmp .cond
    align 16
    .loop:
        cmp [esi+ecx*4], eax
        cmovg eax, [esi+ecx*4]
        cmp [esi+ecx*4], ebx
        cmovl ebx, [esi+ecx*4]
    .cond:
        add ecx, 1
        js .loop
```

P.S. I consider loop-unrolling. And I don't move `[esi+ecx*4]` to the register becasue of the fact that Agner Fog writes that AMD K8 can fetch 6 macroinstructions / 16 bytes per cycle. It is faster than SIMD version.

Am I right that the whole loop is loop-carried dependency because of the partial  register flag dependency?

Comment: I don't see any partial-flag instructions.  `cmp` and `add` always write all the flags.  K8 runs `cmov` with 1c latency, on any of its 3 ALUs, so your loop-carried dependency chain is only 1 cycle.   How fast does this run?

Comment: You should probably load once, instead of 4 times.  K8 can do 2 loads per clock, and has 3 ALUs.  Actually, maybe it's still fine.  4 loads and 6 ALU uops (since add/js don't fuse on AMD) should take 2 cycles per iteration.  Fetch/decode probably isn't the bottleneck.  I forget the pipeline width in K8; is it 4 m-ops per clock or 3 (issue/rename and retirement)?  Anyway, definitely worth trying a separate-load version, and with an unroll by 2 since it's only loop overhead that was saturating the ALU ports.  Also try a branching version (remember, if it's a new max, it can't also be a new min).

Comment: 3 m-ops . Ok, Thanks. I make some experiments with prefetching next line of cache and it helps :) Branch version is too slow.  I tested unrolling by 2 and it also helps.

Comment: When it comes to partial-flag. I meant that flag register is here data dependency because of two `cmp` operations.

Comment: There are never any dependencies on *old* values of flags, only on the flags written by the preceding `cmp` or `add`.  But yes, `cmov` or `setcc` have data dependencies on FLAGS, vs. `jcc` being a control dependency.  This is what people mean when they say `cmov` creates loop-carried dependency chains.

Comment: So, the loop-carried dependency chain is: `cmp [esi+ecx*4], eax -> cmovg eax, [esi+ecx*4] -> cmp [esi+ecx*4],ebx -> cmovl ebx, [esi+ecx*4]`? On my eye it is caused by register flag dependency. After all, before` cmovl ebx, [esi+ecx*4]` can start in the next iteration, the `cmp [esi+ecx*4],ebx` have to be finished. And, so on.

Comment: Register renaming avoids false dependencies on the old value of FLAGS.  The only loop-carried dep chains are `cmovg eax, [esi+ecx*4]` -> the same instruction next iteration (dependency on `eax`), and the same for the other cmov.  (And of course the loop counter).

Comment: Ok, it is clear that there are two loop-carried chain dependency ( I skipped the loop counter). But, you said `cmovg eax, [esi+ecx*4] -> cmovg eax, [esi+ecx*4] (next iteration)` is loop-carried. Why didn't you write: `(1)cmovg eax, [esi+ecx*4] -> (2) cmp [esi+ecx*4], eax (next iteration) -> (1)`? After all, (1) from the previous iteration must be finished before (2) in the next iteration can start ( the register `eax` must be known from previous iteration).

Comment: Oh yes, you're correct, `cmp` in the next iteration does depend on the result of `cmov`.  So the two dep chains involving `cmov` are 2 cycles long on K8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113941/discussion-between-gilgamesz-and-peter-cordes).